# it is a python program to find factorial of a user entered number using recursion. but it generates error "previous lines repeated 995 times"

Tags: python

```
factorial = 1
def fact(a):
    if(a==0):
        return 1
    else:
        return fact(a)*fact(a-1)
num = int(input("Enter a number : "))
print(fact(num))
```

it is a python program to find factorial of a user entered number using recursion. but it generates error

> "previous lines repeated 995 times"

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
def fact(a):
    if a == 0 or a == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return a*fact(a-1)
num = int(input("Enter a number : "))
print(fact(num))
```

The definition of factorial is :
`n! = n * (n - 1)!`
and you are trying : `n! = n! * (n - 1)!`, with the line `fact(a)*fact(a-1)`

Additionally, the variable `factorial` is also not required since it is unused.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of the problem is in the recursive call **(fact(a) * fact(a-1))**

Changing this line to **(a * fact(a-1))** will fix the problem.
Also, optionally, the ***else*** checking can be removed, as it is not required.

**Here is the working example with the updates:**

```
# File name:  factorial.py

factorial = 1

def fact(a):
    if( a<= 1 ):
        return 1
    return (a * fact(a-1))

num = int(input("Enter a number : "))
print(fact(num))
```

**Output:**

```
> python factorial.py

Enter a number : 99

933262154439441526816992388562667004907159682643816214685929638952175999932299156089414639761565182862536979208272237582511852109168640000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your factorial implementation. It should be `fact(a) = a * fact(a-1)`

Try:

```
def fact(a):
    if a == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return a*fact(a-1)
```